# Delete a node given a key in linked list

Tags: java

I have written code to delete a node from linked list given a key. However, when I try to delete the first node here and then traverse my list, it is still showing the first node that previously existed. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? My entire code starting with class name

```
public class LinkedList {
    //removing Node nested class





    public void buildList1() {
        head=new Node(1);
        head.next=new Node(3);
        head.next.next=new Node(5);
        head.next.next.next=new Node(7);


    }

    public boolean removeNode(Node head,int x) {
        //1 3 5 7---to delete 5
        Node q=head;//q
    //  Node p=head.next;//p
        Node prev=null;

        if(q!=null && q.data==x) {
            head=q.next;
            //q=null;
            System.out.println("next to head" + head.data);
            return true;
        }
        while(q!=null && q.data!=x) {
            prev=q;
            q=q.next;
        }
        if(q==null)
            return false;
        prev.next=q.next;

        return true;

    }

    public void printList() 
    { 
        Node tnode = head; 
        while (tnode != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(tnode.data+" "); 
            tnode = tnode.next; 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
        list.buildList1();


        list.printList();
        System.out.println(list.removeNode(list.head, 1));
        list.printList();

    }

}
```

Comment: An aside: `if(q.data==x && q!=null)` the conditions here should be flipped

Comment: Can you provide a more complete set of your code?  Can you post what your entire LinkedList class looks like?  Your `removeNode` method shouldn't be taking in the head node as a parameter.  The head node should be an instance variable of the LinkedList class.

Comment: Your `LinkedList` class should keep track of its own `head`, not take it as a parameter (to _any_ of its methods) -- so it should start as `public class LinkedList { private Node head; ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JD D had a good answer, but I would do the `removeNode` method even easier.

```
public boolean removeNode(int x) {
    tempNode = this.head;
    prevNode = null;
    if (this.head != null && this.head.data == x) {
        this.head = this.head.next;
        return true;
    }
    while (tempNode != null) {
        if (tempNode.data == x) {
            prevNode.next = tempNode.next;
            return true;
        }
        prevNode = tempNode;
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you should put the `if (this.head.date == x)` logic before the loop... no reason to run that check every loop as it doesn't change

Comment: that's true, but it would have to be double condition `if (this.head != null && this.head.data == x)` otherwise it would throw a `NullPointerException` if the `List` would be empty

Answer (score 1):

Add head as instance variable and remove that parameter from your removeNode function.  You should be able to reference this variable in your methods using the `this` keyword.

Something like this (untested, but hope you get the idea):

```
public class LinkedList {
    //removing Node nested class

    private Node head;

    public void buildList1() {
        this.head=new Node(1);
        this.head.next=new Node(3);
        this.head.next.next=new Node(5);
        this.head.next.next.next=new Node(7);


    }

    public boolean removeNode(int x) {
        Node q=this.head;
        Node prev=null;

        if(q!=null && q.data==x) {
            this.head=q.next;
            return true;
        }
        while(q!=null && q.data!=x) {
            prev=q;
            q=q.next;
        }
        if(q==null)
            return false;
        prev.next=q.next;

        return true;

    }

    public void printList() 
    { 
        Node tnode = this.head; 
        while (tnode != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(tnode.data+" "); 
            tnode = tnode.next; 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
        list.buildList1();

        list.printList();
        System.out.println(list.removeNode(1));
        list.printList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
    list.buildList1();
    list.printList();
    list.remove(2);
    list.printList();

}
```

LinkedList has a library of methods, one being remove(int index). Use it as shown.

Comment: There is no such thing as buildList1() or printList() in the built in class.  I think this is some sort of custom class for a school project or something of that nature.

Comment: In which case I would suggest looking at the unlink(Node<E> x) source code. and manipulating it to fit your case.

Comment: This is obviously a personal/school project. Using built in libraries defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your life will be simpler if your `head` node is not be your first node, and your first real node is be `next` of your (fixed) `head`.

That way, you won’t need special code to handle the case when the first (real) node is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the list directly which you have created. Possible two solutions.
First: Use the list created

```
 if (q != null && q.data == x) {
        this.head = q.next;//use this to refer the list you created
        // q=null;
        System.out.println("next to head" + head.data);
        return true;
    }
```

Second: Pass the list itself

```
  public boolean removeNode(LinkedList list, int x) {
    // 1 3 5 7---to delete 5
    Node q = list.head;// q
   }

  //Call it like this
  System.out.println(list.removeNode(list, 1));
```